# Join two table and get the no of records and based on result inner join

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

[image]

**Output one**

1.Get all records of table_one
2.Check the result with table_two with name and year and get reference bid
3.Based on refer bid we can calculate with table_one and get no of duplicate counts in a every year
4.If i change any data in table_one and table_two output  will be change automatically

any one help in php and mysql concept

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you want to know. I think you should learn some SQL and then do these things on your own. There are really good websites to learn SQL, as example https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQL_Tutorial

Comment: No, sorry; you don't get to dump your homework and a picture of your tables here and have someone else do it for you. Make a good faith attempt at doing the work, and come ask us when you get stuck- post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to give us sample data, give us the query you've got so far, and if it runs say why it doesn't produce the expected output. If it doesn't run, give us exact error messages. Asking for a full solution in multiple languages is too much; break your problem down, get the sql right, then write the php. Ask multiple questions if necessary